# How to template Helm to insert templating language from other application?

Tags: templates, kubernetes-helm, go-templates

I have a configMap that has a piece of alerting that looks like this:

```yaml
alert_output:
  outputs:
    - type: webhook
      enabled: true
      template: |
          {{- if ne (print .PolicyType) "Heartbeat" -}}
          {"text": "New Alert\n Type: {{.PolicyType}}\n Details: {{.Description}}"
          {{- end -}}
```

How can I template this in Helm so that the `text` inside the `outputs.template` can be customizable via values file like this?

```yaml
alert_output:
  outputs:
    - type: webhook
      enabled: true
      template: |
          {{- if ne (print .PolicyType) "Heartbeat" -}}
          {"text": {{ .Values.custom_alert_text }}
          {{- end -}}
```

- `valus.yaml`

```yaml
custom_alert_test: "New Alert\n Type: {{.PolicyType}}\n Details: {{.Description}}"
```

Of course the original `{{}}` are interpreted as being the Helm templates instead of the application templating language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do two things to make this work.

In the template itself, you need to cause Helm (or more properly the Go `text/template` engine) to output a `{{` rather than interpret it as template markup.  I've found the easiest way to do this is to write a template block that emits the curly braces:

```
{{/* A template that evaluates to the literal string "{{" */}}
{{"{{"}}- if ne ... -}}
```

The curly braces are not interpreted in the `values.yaml` file so you do not need to make a change there.  However, parsing the YAML file will convert the `\n` escape sequence into a newline character and consume any quoting that might have been there.  Helm includes a [toJson](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list/#type-conversion-functions) function that will render anything to valid JSON, and should do the required quoting and escaping for you.

In your example there also needs to be one more `}` at the end of the line matching the `{` JSON object syntax.

Putting these things together, you should get something like:

```yaml
alert_output:
  outputs:
    - type: webhook
      enabled: true
      template: |
          {{"{{"}}- if ne (print .PolicyType) "Heartbeat" -}}
          {"text": {{ toJson .Values.custom_alert_text }}}
          {{"{{"}}- end -}}
```

You could also assemble the entire object in template language and then serialize that; which would look something like

```yaml
template: |
  {{"{{"}}- if ne (print .PolicyType) "Heartbeat" -}}
  {{ dict "text" .Values.custom_alert_text | toJson }}
  {{"{{"}}- end -}}
```